# bootloader error err:0x7000

Tags: adb, fastboot, stock-android, bootloader-lock

I am trying to unlock my phone's bootloader 
Device techno i3 
I have installed drivers , adb &fastboot 
And when I type 
fastboot oem unlock 
It gives error 
err:0×7000

```
(bootloader)    off-mode-charge: 1
(bootloader)    warranty: yes
(bootloader)    unlocked: no
(bootloader)    secure: yes
(bootloader)    kernel: lk
(bootloader)    product: RLK6737M_65_N
(bootloader)    version-preloader: 0.1.00
(bootloader)    version: 0.5
all: Done!!
Finished. Total time: 0.133s
```

Comment: you probably forgot OEM unlocking in developer options

Comment: @alecxs it is enabled

Comment: try `fastboot flashing unlock` and try latest [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads)

Comment: @alecxs same error even though m using latest platform tools zip

Comment: @alecxs okay.. I have updated it

Comment: ask [repair-center](https://www.tecno-mobile.com/repair-centers) maybe you need unlock code